# 0M error writing file: 5 access is denied

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, iso-image, dd

I'm trying to write ISO on USB using `dd` command: `dd if=evolution-64bit.iso od=\\.\f: bs=4M`. I've launched cmd as **Administrator**, disabled my MSE anti-virus software, but it keeps telling me that `Access is denied`. The full error log:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong? I've also changed USB in case the problem was in it.

Comment: Have you tried `od=\\?\Device\Harddisk1`? Be very careful you don't overwrite your internal drives by mistake though.

Comment: @Karan, I tried, but got another error - 'Error opening output file: 3 The system cannot find the past specified'

Comment: @Karan, it's 'path'. I'm sorry for misspelling.

Comment: What ISO is this? Do you *have* to use dd?

Comment: @Karan it's ArchLinux, the latest version. I don't have to use *dd*, but I tried other variants - they don't work

Comment: Ok, now that I know what you're trying to do, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Go into disk part and clean the drive before copying the ISO.

Open CMD as administrator:

> diskpart
>
> list volume
>
> select volume #
>
> clean
>
> exit

Then copy the iso to your external storage with dd.exe

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie) to transfer the Arch Linux ISO to a USB drive:

[image: 1]

Comment: Rufus is great, but it burns the USB only for 30MB without many files, which were in the original ISO and that's the problem, BUT if I let it to boot in UEFI mode it all will be OK, except the thing that my Win7 is installed in BIOS mode and 2 OSes won't see each other when booting. I tried dozens of solutions and no one helped. The only solution I see here is reinstall Windows in UEFI mode, install ArchLinux in UEFI and be happy, but I don't yet know will it work or not. I will try today, and will post result ASAP.

Comment: Ok, try `of=\\.\Harddisk1` before reinstalling Windows. Also I will let the Rufus developer know about this bug, if it is indeed one and not a problem at your end.

Comment: I tried 2 different USB with Rufus, but I'm not sure whether it's a bug or my bad. I will try your last suggestion within 6-7 hours. I have to go to the highschool ;)

Comment: Ok, good luck and let me know. Meanwhile I left a comment for the Rufus dev so maybe he will see what's up if he has the time. Failure in the middle can indicate a bad drive (or drives in your case, which can happen), but certainly skipping files seems to be a serious issue (especially because even the Arch team recommends Rufus). If you can, I'd still recommend trying with one more USB stick to confirm that it's a problem with Rufus.

Comment: @pushandpop, this is definitely a problem on your end. If Rufus was missing files during ISO copy, that would be a pretty big deal, and I would definitely have heard about it by now (Rufus gets downloaded more than 1 million times a month, so I'd definitely hear if there was a major issue like this).

Also, I have tested the latest Arch with the latest Rufus and found no issue.